# Convert java String to extended ascii charset (codepage 437)

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have to use some strings from UTF-8 external data, and have to create a text file in the old extended ascii dos charset from it (IBM437).
The external data is a bigger set of product names, units and whatnot coming from various countries/regions (couple 10k per region), so i expect a lot of non-dos characters coming in.

Tried `String("ő").getBytes("Cp437")` for example, but it only returns a question mark (#67).

Is there an existing solution to get the 'closest' dos chars available?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can understand your example.  Problems like this typically happen either because of a bug in the application code or mismatch between character encodings used and the source or sink for the encoded characters.

Comment: `ő` can't be encoded in CP437. Why do you expect it to be able to representable in CP437? You seem to be trying to solve the fundamental problem with Codepages: they can't handle text that isn't purely composed of the limited number of characters they support, there's simply no way around this inside this system.

Comment: So you want a program that will map any UTF-8 character into an IBM-437 one? And this mapping will match the UTF-8 character to the visually closest IBM-437? To be sure of your problem, we will need the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What would you expect `ő` to map to in [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set), and why would you expect that?

Comment: @user15358848 just use the normalizer to turn o with tilde into knowing that the base letter is just an o. Definitely don't start parsing the unicode name for a character! See my answer.

Comment: I am aware of what the problem is here, there is no real translation between a 16 and 8bit format.
The question is if anyone knows an existing solution that tries to solve this somehow.
The repro case is up there, mapping ő to either ö or ô would be fine, mapping it to ? is not so great.
As long as i don't have to build a dictionary for this by hand anything that approximates a readable result is great. 
If there is no such existing solution i'll just tell the client it's beyond scope.

Answer (score 2):

> Tried String("ő").getBytes("Cp437") for example, but it only returns a question mark (#67).

That's *probably* because getBytes will replace all unmappable characters with the default replacement character, which is `?` for Cp437. However, there are a ton of caveats so let's first doublecheck everything before continuing:

> `new String("ő")`

This just straight up doesn't work unless your compiler and your editor are in agreement:

- You write that text (or paste it, or whatnot) in your code editor.
- You hit CMD+S or whatnot in your editor to save the file.
- The editor now writes a sack of bytes onto disk, because files are bytes and not characters. To perform this task, your editor applies a charset encoding. Let's say it is applying `UTF-8`. In most editors you can configure this and/or it's visible in a status bar somewhere.
- The compiler now opens the file, which is a sack of bytes, but it wants to parse characters and not bytes. Therefore, it, too, applies a charset encoding to turn those bytes back into characters.
- **If it uses a different encoding, then the `ő` is mangled into a gobbledygook character**.

So, start there. Are you sure javac and your editor are in sync? `javac` has a `--charset` flag, and if you're using a build system, it has a setting for this. I strongly suggest you set it all to UTF-8 everywhere. Alternatively, if you're just not sure how to do any of these things, you can dodge the bullet entirely and write your source code entirely in ASCII characters, that way, encoding is unlikely to matter (you can encode with UTF-8, decode with Cp437, and encode back with iso-8859-1, and nothing gets mangled if the input was all-ASCII):

```
> cat Test.java
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = new String("\u0151");
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
> javac Test.java
> java Test
ő
```

Run the above code right now and double check that it prints `ő`, because processes (like `java.exe`) *also* pipe their data out as a sack of bytes, and the terminal itself is therefore *also* applying charset conversion. If any of this stuff is misconfigured you're going to tie yourself into knots because your tool stack is badly configured. Let's confirm it isn't before continuing.

### Okay, I confirmed javac AND editor is UTF_8, and the above prints ő

Great. Let's continue with:

> `.getBytes("Cp437")`

This then produces a byte array that contains your string, encoded using Cp437.

**Reading documentation is fundamental**.

Let's read the docs of the getBytes method.

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement byte array. The CharsetEncoder class should be used when more control over the encoding process is required.

That sounds like great advice, so let's ditch the code and do what the docs suggest instead:

```
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("Cp437")
  .newEncoder()
  .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
  .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
  ;

CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap("\u0151");
ByteBuffer bb = encoder.encode(cb);
```

Running this we get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
```

Which is telling us that there's a character in there that is not representable in Cp437. This is indeed the case: **The character ő cannot be represented in Cp437**.

Now we get into a 'nobel prize' level complicated story: How do you transliterate a character into the intended more ascii-ish equivalent?

**This is impossible without knowing about input language**.

Here is a trivial example:

In german, the letter `ö`, if you must write it in ascii, is transcribed as `oe`. For example, "Schröder" would transcribe that as "Schroeder" if some website doesn't allow it. (For fun: google "schroeder" and you get some 42 million results; "schroder" only gets you a little less than that).

However, in swedish, the letter `ö` is transcribed as o. For example, in the name "Henrik Samuel Conrad Sjögren", they'd transcribe that as "Sjogren". Searching for Sjogren finds far more hits than Sjoegren - the hits you do get on Sjoegren is **failed transcribing** - automated systems that blindly thought the best way to ascii-ize ö is to make that an oe regardless of context.

The conclusion is that asciifying in the way a human would do it is hard-AI-level difficult.

That leaves the rote transcription strategy of just getting rid of the accents, even if that is language-technically not the right strategy. In other words, to transcribe "Schröder" as "Schroder" even though that's not how a german speaking person would ever do it.

That, you can do in code:

```
String o = "\u0151";
String v = Normalizer.normalize(o, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
v = v.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
System.out.println(v);
> o
```

This will first break that single character into 2 characters: The plain `o`, followed by a special character that means: "Put a double acute on the previous character" (that's what the Normalizer does - splits things into a simple symbol and then a separate character that means: Modify the previous one in some way - this is called 'decompose'). Then, we use a regexp replace all to just get rid of all non-ascii, leaving just the basic ascii `o`. Note that not everything decomposes cleanly like this - characters like 'ß' just turn into nothingness. You presumably wanted that to transcribe to 'ss' - but again, that presupposes that you know the input is german or some other language where 'ß' should transcribe to ss, not a guarantee.

This is asciification, you asked for 'get me the closest letter in Cp437'. I assume you're perhaps thinking of: Hey, Cp437 actually contains an o-umlaut at position 148. However, there's a problem there: Your eyeballs can tell they look similar, but 'looks similar' is not a good way to transcribe. That would suggest you can just replace a capital i (I) with a lowercase L (l) because 'they look similar'.

There is no relationship between the umlaut and the double acute. Other than that they look similarish, but that's all. Double acute is primarily used in hungarian, and the umlaut is primarily used in german and swedish. A real guns and grandmas situation: They have nothing to do with each other.

Thus, if your question is: I want to transcribe ő into ö, I don't think anything exists, you'd have to write such a tool yourself. If you intend on doing this, I strongly suggest you first run your input through a normalizer (normalize the other way, combining base letter + modifier character into a single combined character, and then write a list of character mappings which you then apply. This list would then include `'ő'` to `'ö'`. Based on nothing more than that you think that's how it should be done.

If your question is: I want to transcribe ő into o, the code above does just that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I know the difficulties this task presents.
Question is if there is an existing solution - which obviously will be far from perfect.
As with any problems in IT probably a couple 1000 people bumped into it already, maybe there is a dict up somewhere on the net.
This question is what my time budget allows for, building a full dictionary for several languages is beyond scope.

Comment: I would start by making some stastistics on your input files. I would find the characters that cannot be mapped to cp437. If they are a few hunderds, you can manually create a map. If they are thousands, I don't think you could solve it with a limited budget. I just read your comment - I don't know if a tool exists that automatically maps `ő` to `o` for example, except for the normaliser proposed by @rzwitserloot